# how to create soap messages in ruby and pass them to a web service

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I want to pass a phone number, customer name and sellers number to a web service. But i am new on ruby on rails. I want to know how I can design a soap message getting details from my order form, and then pass them to the web service in my OrderController. Please I need your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Savon](https://github.com/savonrb/savon) for dealing with soap, it works fine and has nice, easy syntax.